# Composer requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I'm using symfony3 to build a web app, when i try to install several external bundles, i get

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.

I tried with the option `--ignore-platform-reqs` but same thing happens.
These bundles only work on symfony2? i thought symfony3 is fully backward-compatible? 
Are there more configs for composer in order to make the install?

PS: PHP 5.5.8

Edit: composer.json

```
{
  "name": "dell/.checkout",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "type": "project",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "app/AppKernel.php",
      "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "v2.8.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.0-alpha1",
    "blackknight467/star-rating-bundle": "v2.0.1",
    "nomaya/social-bundle": "dev-master",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "2.0.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "5.5.9"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: depends by the bundles are aligned with the new sf3 version. try to post your `composer.json` files

Comment: @Matteo but why would it not work? its backward compatible anyways? (updated with composer.json)

Comment: the `ignore-platform-reqs` skip only platform requirements (i.e. the php version etc) check the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform)

Comment: so there s no solution?

Comment: you should fix the bundle dependency.  :(

Comment: i should? how? isnt the bundle create in charge with that?

Answer (score 0):

According [this issue on Github](https://github.com/nomayann/NomayaSocialButtonsBundle/issues/10), the owner of the [`nomaya/social-bundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/nomaya/social-bundle) does not intend to support Symfony 3, so you are likely seeing backwards compatibility issues. There might be more, but that's the first one I spotted.

[Symfony's Backwards Compatability Promise](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/bc.html) says this:

> Ensuring smooth upgrades of your projects is our first priority.
>   That's why we promise you backwards compatibility (BC) for all minor
>   Symfony releases. You probably recognize this strategy as Semantic
>   Versioning. In short, Semantic Versioning means that only **major
>   releases (such as 2.0, 3.0 etc.) are allowed to break backwards
>   compatibility**. Minor releases (such as 2.5, 2.6 etc.) may introduce
>   new features, but must do so without breaking the existing API of that
>   release branch (2.x in the previous example).